# Real data examples for the Neyman-Pearson lemma?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, teaching

Are there any interesting (and preferably published for that reason) real data examples to which the Neyman-Pearson lemma for simple binary testing or classification problems applies directly?

I am not thinking here, for example, about certain composite (as opposed to simple) testing problems in models with monontone likelihood ratios, to which the Neyman-Pearson lemma applies a bit indirectly.